# Converting floats back to timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp

I want to convert floats like this "[1.6205184e+09]" back into a timestamp.

First I created the floats like this :

```
temp_array = np.array([(i - datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)) / datetime.timedelta(seconds=1) for i in ar])
y_new = temp_array.astype('float')
```

I used them for regression. Now I need to convert this array back to timestamps.
How do I do this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the original dates by simply adding the float time in seconds to your offset time `datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)`:

```py
import datetime as dt

restored = np.array([dt.date(1970, 1, 1) + dt.timedelta(seconds=x) for x in y_new])
```

Comment: thanky for the answer. Unfortunalety I receive this error:
unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: numpy.ndarray

Comment: This is due to the shape of your `y_new` array. From your example the implication was that it was one dimensional and contained floats. You can figure out how to structure the list comprehension to solve this issue :)